# Using present perfect vs past simple in a context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, past-tense, present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence is more applicable to use :

1-Thank you, you got us this far.

2-Thank you, you have gotten us this far.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the meanings of those two expressions.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty   Thank you. I believe that too, but I think it is better to use the present perfect.